# How to produce a closed contour on XYZ data?

Tags: matlab, plot, contour

I would like to create the nearest closed contour right now when I do contour its broken in chunks. Here is the picture of contour:

[image]

I wanted a closed contour around the center.

I need something like this

[image]

```
axes(handles.axes1);
cla(handles.axes1);

hold on;
pcolor(xC,yC,z_Diff); shading flat
colormap(handles.axes1, 'jet');
freezeColors(handles.axes1)


[C,hfigc] = contour(xC,yC,z_Diff,[thresh_crater thresh_crater]);
set(hfigc, ...
    'LineWidth',1.0, ...
    'Color', [1 0 0]);
hold off;
```

I am trying enclose a box around the crater area which include the hole and outer piled stuff:

I am getting the results below based on largest contour area:

[image]

Here is the image I want it to be like this:

[image]

This will be problem if i have more than 1 crater and i want to box them.

Comment: can you show us what it would look like what you want? with paint or wahtever

Comment: And please show some code, see [mcve]

Comment: Change the threshold levels? Or are you asking how to choose the levels? beacuse this, as it is, is just adding a number to that code

Comment: I need a closed contour at 0.2 but it produces mutliple lines, is there any way to join the nearest contour lines.

Comment: But..... If you do that, then the contour lines are not contour lines anymore..... it defeats the purpose of contour lines.... Also, to get the blue are, just set the contour to around `-0.4`. Its kind of ovbious from the colorbar

Comment: I edited the question to clarify the problem i am having